# I thought methods are not reactive but why in this example the method is reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-pine-542q4?file=/src/App.vue

I created a short example. Look at the method: `iAmAMethod`. I use it directly in the view template section. In that method I use a reactive data prop `counter` but it seems that the section of that template gets re-rendered when the var `counter` increments. But why does this work? I thought methods are not reactive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are methods in Vue reactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636004/are-methods-in-vue-reactive)

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Vue, values' being reactive means that their state (properties) are tracked and their `setter`s are intercepted to trigger re-rendering.

[Related part in docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked)

In contrast, methods of components are not reactive, because changing their properties doesn't trigger re-rendering.

In your sample, you don't change properties of `iAmAMethod` method, but you change the `counter` data which is reactive. That's why Vue re-renders the template.